# Is gtest and googletest libraries the same? If so, why are there two libraries?

Tags: googletest

I see that there are two libraries - gtest and googletest.
They seem to work interchangeably.
I am interested to know if there is any difference between the two.
If so, what it is.

In a yocto project that I am currently working on, I see that some recipes has dependency on gtest.
Some have dependency on googletest.
Each recipe compiles successfully individually.
But the full image build fails due to conflict between these libraries.

I tried to replace gtest with googletest and I found no compilation issues.

Comment: There is no such a library googletest, you mean gtest and gmock

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if You are using the [meta-openembedded](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded) gtest is an [alias for googletest](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/def4759e95fc8e20272fb337ac349c2fddab357e/meta-oe/recipes-test/googletest/googletest_1.13.0.bb#L7).

See bitbake documentation on [PROVIDES](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html?highlight=alias#term-PROVIDES)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34515108)